# Linux - Create home router secured with WPA2

Tags: linux, home-networking, wireless-router

I am planning to create a home router using my Linux laptop.  Is it possible to secure the wireless router with WPA2, and how would I set that up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/) and can configure WPA2 through HostAPD.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your wireless router model. The only way you can access your router is by it's default IP and to know that, we need to know the manufacturer of your router. Reply with your router manufacturer for further info pertaining to securing the router with WPA2.

Comment: I think the OP is talking about using the laptop as the router...

Comment: So he wants to create the router using his laptop? But he wants to secure the *wireless router* with WPA2? Sorta confused now.

Comment: I want to use my laptop as the wireless router and secure the connection with WPA2. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, you can create an ad-hoc network. What distro of Linux are you using?

Comment: I am using Gentoo Linux - I was planning on setting up dhcp and other services as well on the box so that clients accessing it will see it as any other access point.  With DHCP, I can filter who connects by MAC address fairly easily.

Comment: This was the only instructional method that I could find, basic how-to in setting up ad-hoc with DHCP. Not sure about the WPA2 security though. Here's the link - http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-274790-highlight-adhoc+wireless.html